# How do I fix MathJax formatting error in collapsed div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mathjax

I'm using MathJax to display math in a webpage. I'm also using Bootstrap 3. MathJax tries to match the size of the math with that of the text where it is placed. For the most part, the math displays well. However, when the math is in a "[collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)" div, i.e.

```
<div class="collapse">
   <!-- Math here -->
</div>
```

it is displayed *larger* than its surrounding text. The only difference between the math displayed as expected and the math displayed larger than expected is that the latter is in a div with class="collapse".

Another important piece of the puzzle is that I use the following Latex font, which is included in my css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "latex";
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,T1R...gP5w/kP+RAA format("opentype");
}
```

I assign this font ("latex") to my text. The MathJax inconsistency occurs when I use this font, and not otherwise.

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyftw08w/1/

**Question: Is there a way to fix this problem, and if so, what is the solution?**

Comment: Please add a live code snippet.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to fix this problem:

If the originally collapsable item starts out uncollapsed (i.e. content is shown) when the page loads, then the problem goes away. To show the content, you can add "in" to the div class:

```
<div class="collapse in">
    <!-- Math here -->
</div>
```

Then once the MathJax content is loaded, you can collapse this div by removing "in". To do this, add the following at the end of the tag that configures MathJax:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
    $(".collapse").removeClass("in");
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heddtg73/1/